# How display the table rows in view by multi-dimensional array using Codeigniter 2.2.6 version

Tags: codeigniter-2

How display the table rows in view by inserting or passing multi-dimensional array in `codeignator 2.2.6 version`.

[image: 1]

**my template** (my view file:)

```
<table>
<thead>
     <tr>
         <th>City</th>
         <th>Hotel</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <?php if((sizeof($result))>0){

        $array =  explode(',',$result->city);

            foreach($array as $info){
            ?>
                <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $info ;?></td>
                   <?php 
                    $arrays =  explode(',',$result->hotel_aboard);
                   foreach($arrays as $infos){?>
                   <td><?php echo $infos ;?></td>
                <?php } ?>
                 </tr>

            <?php
            } 

      }else{ ?>
            <tr><td colspan='3'>Data Not Found</td></tr>
       <?php } ?>
 </tbody>

</table>
```

output:
my output display as below as shown but I need two columns not that third column geeting output double time
[image: my output display as below as shown but I need two columns not that third column geeting output double time]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: ya sure guys definitely  i post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi guys i found solution lastly since i have been worked hard from 5 days hours and hours i have been an a link just follow the flow

"https://eval.in/376541"